# iText - roundRectangle with no border

Tags: itext, border

Is it possible to have a roundRectangle with no border?  The following code creates roundRectangles and rectangles with border sizes of 0f and 1f.  For the roundRectangle there is still a visible border when the lineWidth is set to 0f, but this is not true for a rectangle with a border of 0f.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
    magazine = new Document(PageSize.LETTER,0,0,0,0);
    pdfw = PdfWriter.getInstance(magazine, new FileOutputStream("out.pdf"));
    magazine.open();

    canvas = pdfw.getDirectContent();

    canvas.rectangle(0,0,600,750);
    canvas.setColorFill(BaseColor.ORANGE);
    canvas.fillStroke();

    canvas.setColorStroke(BaseColor.BLACK);
    canvas.setColorFill(BaseColor.GRAY);
    canvas.setLineWidth(1f);

    llx = 100;
    lly = 100;
    wid = 100;
    hei = 100;
    canvas.roundRectangle(llx,lly, wid, hei, 10);
    canvas.fillStroke();

    llx = 100;
    lly = 210;
    wid = 100;
    hei = 100;
    canvas.rectangle(llx,lly, wid, hei);
    canvas.fillStroke();

    canvas.setColorStroke(BaseColor.BLACK);
    canvas.setColorFill(BaseColor.WHITE);
    canvas.setLineWidth(0f);

    llx = 210;
    lly = 100;
    wid = 100;
    hei = 100;
    canvas.roundRectangle(llx,lly, wid, hei, 10);
    canvas.fillStroke();

    llx = 210;
    lly = 210;
    wid = 100;
    hei = 100;
    canvas.rectangle(llx,lly, wid, hei );
    canvas.fillStroke();
```

Comment: *this is not true for a rectangle with a border of 0f* - that would be an error, as **A line width of 0 shall denote the thinnest line that can be rendered at device resolution: 1 device pixel wide,** cf. the specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you draw lines and shapes in PDF, you use *path construction operators*. The following method introduces an `re` (rectangle) operator to construct a rectangle.

```
canvas.rectangle(0,0,600,750);
```

iText also provides convenience methods. For instance: the following method introduces a sequence of `m` (move to), `l` (line to), `c` (curve to),... operators:

```
canvas.roundRectangle(llx,lly, wid, hei, 10);
```

As soon as you have constructed the path, you can use a *path painting operator* to actually draw something. iText has different `fill()`, `stroke()` and `fillStroke()` variations.

You are using this method:

```
canvas.fillStroke();
```

This means that you fill the path with the fill color and stroke the path with the stroke color. In your question, you indicate that you only want to fill the path (you want to color what's inside the rounded rectangle); you do not want to stroke it (you don't want to draw the border of the rounded rectangle).

This is easy to achieve. Just replace `fillStroke()` by `fill()`:

```
canvas.fill();
```

Now you will only fill the rounded rectangle and not stroke its border.

**Comment by mkl:**

> A line width of 0 shall denote the thinnest line that can be rendered at device resolution: 1 device pixel wide.

This is correct. It is a common misconception that changing the width of a line to 0 means that the line isn't drawn when invoking `stroke()`. If you don't want to see a line, the solution is simple: don't *stroke* it.